# Circular aperture in optical instruments

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Why do almost all the optical instruments have a circular aperture to gather light? For example, objective lens of telescope, shape of pupil, lens of camera and so on. Can anyone please explain me relating it to resolving power?

Comment: Many animals do not have round pupils, but in any case that's not a physics question, but a biology one.

Answer (score 1):

There's [plenty of telescopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_mirror#Telescopes_using_segmented_mirrors) that use non-circular primary mirrors, particularly when they are composite mirrors made up of multiple individual components:

[image]

<sup>[Image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Comparison_optical_telescope_primary_mirrors.svg)</sup>

Circular primaries, along with lenses and other optical elements, *tend* to be easier to manufacture and to polish, because if the target shape is symmetrical then you can use a symmetrical construction / polishing method (see e.g. [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4FBKbNY258) for an example in action). However, once you get to a certain size, it becomes impossible to build single-piece primary mirrors, and you need to move to a segmented primary (which also handles adaptive optics better), in which case the preferred shape is a collection of hexagons, which provide the best tesselation of the plane.

For your run-of-the-mill camera lens, if the element is symmetric then that allows for a symmetric shaping, which helps avoid [astigmatism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astigmatism_(optical_systems)) - an otherwise generic type of aberration that occurs in cylindrically-asymmetric systems. You *can* polish a square lens so that it is astigmatism-free, but it's more work than for a circular one.

And as for camera apertures, while *some* shutters try to approximate a circular aperture by a polygon with lots of sides ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUgQQ.jpg)), there's plenty of cameras out there with straight shutters that travel linearly:

[image]

<sup>[Image source](https://petapixel.com/2015/01/29/exploring-dslr-shutters-work-10000-frames-per-second/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Lenses could be made rectangular, or nearly any other shape, but they would prove to be less practical and harder to manufacture than circular ones.

For example, the sensor in a camera is rectangular, but that's only because we are used to the convention of rectangular pictures in stead of round ones.